# How can i retain my site traffic and promotions after change my hosting service

Tags: web-hosting, magento

Now am working with Bigcommerce, i am ready to move magento with hosting provider Godaddy. After am migrating how can i retain my site traffic.

What is the basic steps to take retain Website traffic.

Comment: Are you keeping the same domain?

Comment: yes. same domain name

Comment: Can we assume that the URI (path and file names of URL) are changing?

Comment: No, still am using off page seo for my new hosting.